# Rendering SSRS Report located in _layouts folder?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

Does anyone have any knowledge on how to load an SSRS report located in the `_layouts` folder?

I am able to load it if it's in a document library and here is the URL that it has: `http://mysite/rootsite/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/rootsite/Documents/ssrsreport.rdl`

If I change the path from the rootsite to the `/_layouts/15/ssrsreport.rdl`, it throws an error that it cannot find the item.

I am trying to make this report available for the whole environment.

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
this.ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
path = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\<<ProjectName>>\<<FileName.rdlc>>"; 
....
.. You code goes here
....
this.ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = path;
```

Replace `<<ProjectName>>` with your project name and
Replace `<<FileName.rdlc>>` with your rdlc file name

Comment: I am not in C#, The rdl report is loaded by the RSViewerPage in SharePoint. This method you mentioned above will not work in this case.

Comment: oh.. okay.. will check and let you know by tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Based on a recent install of Sharepoint 2010 I've learned that you have to hunt around for the proper string to get the ReportServer to fire. Here's something similar to what I had to use that may point you in the right direction:

```
http://mysite/_vti_bin/reportserver?http://mysite/rootsite/_layouts/15/ssrsreport.rdl
```

Let us know if that works.